# Clearcase: consolidating UCM vobs and components

Tags: clearcase

There are two scenarios:
- We have created a number of components each in their own vobs and realize now we prefer to keep them within a single vob
- We have created a component inside what ends up being the incorrect vob.

In both cases, the vobs are UCM vobs (CQ enabled) and have had projects, development activities delivered and baselines created, etc.
Our objective is to reorganize the components and code into the desired location.
Rational support indicates there is no method to achieve this:
[Move UCM components between PVOBs](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135093)
Do you have any strategies for accomplishing this while retaining the relevant information?

The simple approach would be to extract the current baseline and check that code into a new component in the correct vob as a  new baseline, then obsolete the component in the old vob. Any other suggestions?

We are using Clearcase 7.0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Those reorganization processes always involve, with UCM, to duplicate the few latest baselines of those components into the new UCM destination component, and then keeping the old history.
(with CC7.0.x as well as latest CC7.1.2)

That is why I would suggest to *lock* the old components/streams/projects, but not to *obsolete* them, in order for the version trees of the old elements to still be visible (for reference).

Note that moving an element between components is possible is the "new ClearCase" called [Jazz VCS, part of RTC -- Rational Team Concert --](https://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/features/scm), as explained in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=37038&sid=b544c811fd68b8341ffe192406d77081): "`Team > Move in Repository`" (albeit only for [top level directory](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=43820)).

That is why the [technote you reference](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135093) states (for *ClearCase* refactoring between components):

> The decision was made by Product Management to exclude the addition of this feature from future upgrades and releases due to the significant architectural changes required to implement the solution.

It will stay that way forever with ClearCase, since ClearCase has been rewritten already... but as a module of RTC.